# Does there exist such natural number, formed only by digits 0 and 2, that is a power k(k>=2) of another natural number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I tried to rewrite this number using decimal representation but I don't know what to do after that. I'm quite weak at elementary number theory so I think there might even be some trick that I'm not familiar with

Answer (score 2):

Suppose it ends in $m$ zeros.  How many powers of $5$ does it have?  How many powers of $2$?

Comment: Well, than It surely has m powers of 2 and m powers of 5, but we've got some 2-s before these zeroes, so I don't see how can this help

Comment: Cross off the zeroes, then divide by how many more 2s before the result is odd?

Comment: What's than? I'll just get to some power of 5, but it won't be the number I'm searching for. Seems like I don't understand your approach at all

Comment: You have $m$ fives, so the exponent is a factor of $m$.  You have $m+1$ twos, so the exponent is a factor of $m+1$

Comment: Yeah, I got to this point, but from there we want m+1 to be a factor of m in order for this number (200000...000) to be a power of m. But that's impossible

Comment: Yes, if $k$ is a factor of both $m+1$ and $m$ then it is also a factor of $m+1-m=1$.  So there are no solutions.

Comment: But this is only for a case where we have only one two before these zeroes. We can have an infinite amount of permutations of zeroes and twos in front

Comment: After you remove the zeros at the end, you can only divide by two once more before what's left is odd, made of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Oh, I got it. But how to prove there's no perfect power of 2 formed by only 0-s and 1-s?

Comment: No matter whether the number ends with $02$ or with $22$ , it is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$ which digits come before does not matter. Therefore the exponent belonging to $2$ is as mentioned , one larger than the exponent belonging to $5$ (possibly $0$) Since the exponents are coprime , the number cannot be a perfect power.

Comment: That a number with zeros and ones cannot be a power of two (except $1$) is obvious since the ending digit of a power of $2$ can be neither $0$ nor $1$. But anyway this is not necessary since it is covered with the given argument.